# React Select Typescript event type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have this handleSelect:

```
const handlerSelectBank = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    buttonDisabled: false,
    selectedBank: event
  });
};
```

But I got this error:

`Type 'ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown; }>' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)`

This is the initial value of state:

```
const defaultState = {
  buttonDisabled: true,
  selectedBank: null
};
```

What type should I use on `event`?

Comment: Have the same eslint error

Comment: It should be `const handlerSelectBank = (event: type_of_your_value | null) => ..`, So, maybe `(event: string |null)` by guessing that you need a string for `selectedBank`. It should show you in your editor (e.g. VSCode) when you hover mouse over the `onChange` props of react-select.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:react-select].  Is this about the react-select package, or just a `select` element in React?  The answer might be different.

Comment: But for sure the issue if with your `defaultState`.  If it has `selectedBank: null` then you need to assign a type to it where `selectedBank` is the union of `null` and something else.  Otherwise it can only ever be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I also use TypeScript and React. Try this Event type:

```
  function handlerSelectBank (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    setState({
      ...state,
      buttonDisabled: false,
      selectedBank: e.currentTarget.value
    })
  }
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

Answer (score 0):

#### State Type

> is not assignable to type 'null'

Your state is defined such that `selectedBank` can only be `null` and anything else will give an error.  Since your `defaultState` has `selectedBank: null`, Typescript will infer the type for this property as `null` unless you tell it otherwise.

You can declare the type for the state either by assigning a type to the `defaultValue` variable

```
const defaultState: MyState = {
```

or the generic on the `useState` hook

```
const [state, setState] = useState<MyState>(defaultState);
```

You just need one of those, not both.

The type for `MyState` should be such that `selectedBank` can be `null`, but can also be the value that you want.

#### Event Type

I am assuming that the [react-select](/questions/tagged/react-select) tag means you are using the [react-select](https://react-select.com/) package?  Different packages and components define their own change event types.  react-select calls `onChange` with two arguments which are the option and an `ActionMeta` object.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

interface Bank {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

type MyState = {
  buttonDisabled: boolean;
  selectedBank: Bank | null;
};

export const MyComponent = ({ options }: { options: Bank[] }) => {
  const defaultState: MyState = {
    buttonDisabled: true,
    selectedBank: null
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);

  function handlerSelectBank(selectedBank: Bank | null) {
    setState({
      ...state,
      buttonDisabled: false,
      selectedBank
    });
  }

  return (
    <Select
      value={state.selectedBank}
      options={options}
      onChange={handlerSelectBank}
    />
  );
};
```

It might be easier to have separate `useState` hooks for separate pieces of data.